# Javascript error: expected a string but got a object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working with a third party affiliate program provider called Rewardful and trying to integrate them with my website. I know I have integrated them correctly as when I put into the console: `Rewardful.affiliate` it properly outputs the JSON response which is of the form:

```
{
  id: "b533bfca-7c70-4dec-9691-e136a8d9a26c",
  name: "James Bond",
  first_name: "James",
  last_name: "Bond",
  token: "james007"
}
```

However, I am trying to save this information to my database using Rewardful's script:

```
var affiliate;
rewardful('ready', function() {
  if(Rewardful.affiliate) {
    affiliate = Rewardful.affiliate;
  }
});
```

but I keep getting the error shown in the console: `Expected a string but got a object (original data: {"id": "b533bfca-7c70-4dec-9691-e136a8d9a26c", "name": ...` which is the same as the above except its getting returned in the form which starts with `original data`.

How do I extract the actual json response from this object? I have tried `Object.entries(Rewardful.affiliate)[0]` but that gives me the same error but strips out `name`, `last_name`, `first_name` and `token`.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You probably need to use `JSON.stringify(Rewardful.affiliate)`

Comment: That's it!!! Thanks so much. If you want to post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Can't post an answer to a closed question.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help